# Need a VBA Script to replace data in one sheet with data in another

Tags: vba, excel

I have little to no VBA experience, but I have developed high level code in the past. I need a simple VBA script for my Workbook that I’m using. I have searched the web for solutions but I haven’t been able to find exactly what I need.
I have one Workbook with two worksheets (Ex: Sheet1 and Sheet2).

•   Sheet1 has two columns (Column A (contains a Name) and Column B (Contains a Numerical Value). For example:

```
A        B
Smith   1236
Jones   7643
White   2344
Thomas  9022
Greene  5221
Holmes  3287
Jackson 9932
```

•   Sheet2 has multiple columns, but I need to select a single column (for example ColumnJ) in Sheet2. The cells in ColumnJ may or may not contain one of the names in Sheet1/ColumnA. If the name appears in a cell in Sheet2/ColumnJ. I need to replace that name with the Numerical value from Sheet1/ColumnB

```
A        B      C       D       …       J        …      Z
Smith   1236    Data    Data    Data    White   Data    Data
Jones   7643    Data    Data    Data    Jackson Data    Data
White   2344    Data    Data    Data    Wilson  Data    Data
Thomas  9022    Data    Data    Data    Holmes  Data    Data
Greene  5221    Data    Data    Data    Black   Data    Data
Holmes  3287    Data    Data    Data    Jones   Data    Data
Jackson 9932    Data    Data    Data    White   Data    Data
```

Sheeet2 Prior to running VBA script

```
A       B        C    D …   J   …   Z
Data    Data    Data    Data    Data    2344    Data    Data
Data    Data    Data    Data    Data    9932    Data    Data
Data    Data    Data    Data    Data        Data    Data
Data    Data    Data    Data    Data    3287    Data    Data
Data    Data    Data    Data    Data        Data    Data
Data    Data    Data    Data    Data    7643    Data    Data
Data    Data    Data    Data    Data    2344    Data    Data
```

Sheet2 After Running VBA script

Comment: And have you tried anything? ([Suggested read](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I do agree with Tim, I'll give you some leway, first post, just try to show some attempt, give us something to manipulate.

try this code:

```
Sub DropThat()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim name As String, value As Long, i As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
i = 1
j = 1
lastrow1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Do While i < lastrow1 + 1
name = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).value
value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).value
Do While j < lastrow2 + 1
If Sheets("Sheet2").Range("J" & j) = name Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("J" & j) = value
End If
j = j + 1
Loop
j = 1
i = i + 1
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```