# Macro to find and replace cell with values from a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help writing a Macro to find cells in one sheet, then replace the cells with data from a different sheet.   I have searched far and wide but my VBA knowledge is quite limited so am not sure what the coding is doing in other answers.

I have a spreadsheet with the names and locations of people in the organization like the one below (call it Sheet1).
[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBXfZ.png)

And another similar sheet that tracks where people are temporarily located (Sheet2).
[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QqDI.png)

What I want is a Macro that searches Sheet1 for the people in Sheet2, and replaces the location in Sheet1 with the temporary location from Sheet2. The search needs to match LastName, FirstName, and Last4 to ensure its replacing the location for the right person.  The actual spreadsheet includes hundreds of people so its not uncommon to have multiple people with the same name.

I've found a similar issue in another thread: [Need a VBA Script to replace data in one sheet with data in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080769/need-a-vba-script-to-replace-data-in-one-sheet-with-data-in-another?rq=1)

I know enough to understand what this script is doing.  What I need help with is getting it to search Sheet2 for multiple criteria that matches Sheet1 before replacing the cell.  This script only matches one name, and I need it to match a LastName, FirstName, and Last4.

Hope that makes sense.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Without telling us what troubles you are encountering in writing your macro, it is very hard for us to help you.  Please explain clearly what is the current problem you are having.

Comment: record a macro of doing the task that you want. then have a look at the resulting code for ideas about your final project code.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, this is my first time posting.  I've found another thread with a similar issue to mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080769/need-a-vba-script-to-replace-data-in-one-sheet-with-data-in-another?rq=1    What I need help with is how do I search Sheet2 for multiple criteria matching with Sheet1 before replacing the data in Sheet2.  The script here only searches for one name that matches.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use VBA, use a Function. It will be simpler and quicker. Create a hidden column and concatenate your three columns into one string (=A2&B2&c3)
Then do the same in sheet 2
Then use INDEX and MATCH to search sheet 2 for that concatenated value. If found show the location from sheet2 otherwise show that from sheet1

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I don't think this will work for me.  The worksheet I'm trying to build compiles multiple reports that are exported to excel from another program. So Sheet2 is created new each time the reports are run.  I'd rather have a macro so I don't have to insert hidden columns each time.

Comment: Use a macro to add the columns and formulas - you can record your actions to get that macro (or at least the essential elements).